# Edit product variation attribute values on checkout/cart page (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to know how can i change a product variation attribute value (thursday value to sunday for example) on checkout/cart page.  Can you help with that please?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Of course that is possible.
Please Use Woo Update Variations In Cart plugin.
that's plugin link given below : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-update-variations-in-cart/

in the woo-update-variations-in-cart-ck.php file replace the line

```
var baseUrl = $(location).attr('hostname');
```

with

```
var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
```